# Confusion: Tensor norm between LCSs

Tags: functional-analysis, tensors, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Recently I have read that one may define a "tensor norm" on the projective tensor product $X\otimes_{\pi} Y$ between two locally convex spaces.  If $X$ and $Y$ are not Banach spaces, how is this possible?  Do we take the quotient by the ideal
$$
\left\{
ker(p\otimes q): p,q \mbox{ seminorms on $X$ and $Y$ respectively}
\right\}?
$$

Comment: Is it possible that was was meant is that the topology on $X \otimes_\pi Y$ arises from a family of seminorms arising in essentially the same way as the tensor norm in the Banach space case?

Comment: I was thinking that they take the projective limit of $X_{p_i}\otimes Y_{q_j}$ where $X_{p_i}$ is the co-kernel of the $i^{th}$ semi-norm on $X$ (likewise for $Y_{q_j}$).... Since in that case each $X_{p_i}$ and $Y_{q_j}$ is normed and LCS is closed under projective limits....

But this is just a guess and maybe I'm a n00b :P

Comment: Where did you read this? It would be easier to guess what was meant by looking there

Comment: At the (near) very beginning of Chapter 35 of : A. Defant, K. Floret - Tensor norms and operator ideals-North-Holland (1993)... I beleive

Comment: If I understand correctly from a brief reading of the beginning of that chapter, they never really define a tensor norm and only something they call the "tensor norm topology". This is just the topology you get from the family of seminorms obtained by applying the construction of the projective tensor norm in the Banach space case to the families of seminorms inducing the topologies of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Oh ya?  Then what's up with the terminology norm...this is basically what's throwing me off..

Comment: Ah, for them "tensor norm" means something else! Basically, when taking the tensor product you have a bunch of different choices for reasonable norms (one of which is the projective norm). For them, a tensor norm is a map that assigns to each pair of normed spaces, a suitable norm on their algebraic tensor product. So for example, the map that just always picks the projective norm on the tensor product is a tensor norm in their language. See 12.1 for their definition of a tensor norm and 35.2 for their construction of the product (which coincides with my description in this special case)

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense.  Thanks so much Ryan... So in this case, the "injective norm topology" in our sense would be the weakest such topology on $X\otimes Y$?